# How to pass data down to a component property in React?

Tags: reactjs

Many React components allow passing custom components as props, in order to customize certain parts of the UI. A popular example would be [react-select](https://react-select.com/components), which allows to specify custom replacements for all its individual sub components.

In this example, I'm using a modal dialog component that allows specifying custom footer component in its `components` prop:

```
const Footer = () => <button>Close</button>;

const MyModal = ({ onClose, closeLabel }) => <Modal components={{ footer: Footer }}/>;
```

I would like to pass certain data down to the custom component. In this particular example, I would like to pass down the `onClose` and `closeLabel` props to the `Footer` component. What I could do is to declare the `Footer` component inline:

```
const MyModal = ({ onClose, closeLabel }) => (
    <Modal
        components={{ footer: () => <button onClick={onClose}>{closeLabel}</button> }}
    />
);
```

The problem with this approach is that every time `MyModal` is rendered, a new `footer` component is created, which causes React to completely recreate the footer DOM. In this simple example that wouldn't be a big problem, but in more complex scenarios it would make things slow and also cause the component to lose its state. Wrapping the footer component in `useCallback()` would partially solve the problem, but only as long as none of the values passed down into the footer component change.

I could use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass down the value, but that seems like a really complicated solution for a really simple problem. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I’m on mobile so I can’t be very detailed. But you need to create a component factory and pass props that way. I hope this helps.

Comment: can you use the Footer as a child in the Modal?

Comment: Are you using `react-select` or is it just an example?

Comment: I'm not using `react-select` in this particular case, it was just a popular example for this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something similar like this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <MyModal>
      <Footer /> // this will get the new props
    </MyModal>
  );
}

const Footer = ({ onClose, closeLabel }) => (
  <button onClick={onClose}>{closeLabel}</button>
);

const MyModal = ({
  onClose,
  closeLabel,
  children // here any child you pass to this component will have both onClose and closeLabel as props
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, {
          onClose,
          closeLabel
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

but anyways there is something not clear there in your code, if you are getting the `onClose` and `closeLabel` as props inside `MyModal` why just don't pass them to the `Footer` from where are you getting them? and if you don't have control over `Modal` component then you can't do anything else than giving it inline

Comment: I don't have control over the `Modal` component, it comes from a library.

Comment: Without access to Modal component I believe Context is your only solution.